# Running a neutral wire to a switch box

Tags: code-compliance, canada

I live in **Ontario, Canada**.  My place was wired pre 2011 code, so it doesn't have a neutral in (most of?) the switch boxes.  I would think that the easiest way to fix this is to run a neutral line from the light to the box.  My question is, is this to code?

### Edit

I've used an endoscope, and I can see that all of the wires are separate within the conduit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a neutral straight from panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132238/adding-a-neutral-straight-from-panel)

Comment: See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/137014/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-neutral-wire-for-smart-switch.

Comment: Hi @isherwood, I don't think that those directly answer my question if running an additional line from my light box to my switch box is to code.

Comment: @isherwood, are you referring to "*Proper wiring methods* (NEC Chapter 3) must be used. It's not allowed to simply toss a single THHN wire alongside an existing Romex because THHN isn't listed to be installed that way."?

Comment: A single neutral wire would be a code violation in the US not sure about code up north . If the original was run in conduit then you could add but that is rarely the case.

Comment: I think answers on either question mention that you can't run conductors in separate raceways. Since you presumably have NM-B jacketed cable now, you can't run another conductor outside that cable's jacket. If that's not the case, please revise to add all necessary detail. The fact that you're running between a switch and a light and not from the panel is irrelevant.

Comment: Lots of people are close happy first the linked answer was not accepted and it was from 2018 code and most likely for a US person 3 reasons this is not the same without a code citation from Canada I know we are close but we do differ.

Comment: Ok @isherwood, good to know.  Yes, the original was run in conduit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your wiring is in conduit, and there is room in the conduit for another wire, then you can pull another wire into the switch box for a neutral.

You would go back to the box of the fixture the switch controls in which there is a paired hot and neutral and pull a neutral from there into the switch box. Personally, I have never worked with conduit so I can't say what are the practical difficulties in doing this, but I  cannot imagine that this would be disallowed by code.

I imagine one way to do this might be to use the existing switched hot wire to pull two wires from the fixture box into the switch box, one would be the neutral and the other would be a replacement for the wire you are using to pull.

Comment: Ok. That's what I figured. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to follow (in the conduit) the same hot and switched-hot wires.  Follow the switched-hot to the lamp itself; there, a neutral must be present.  Tap the neutral **from there**.

Do not tap the neutral from any convenient location.  Only the other end of the switched-hot wire.